# Наибольшая сумма подпоследовательности

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дана последовательность натуральных цифр: [8] = -1 3 -2 5 3 -5 2 2
Требуется найти максимальную сумму подпоследовательности, в данном примере: 3 - 2 + 5 + 3 = 9
Я решаю данную задачу следующим образом, сохраняю индексы с положительными числами. Нахожу массив с суммами, ищу максимум в интервалах с положительными индексами, однако получаю ответ: 11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    vector <int> numbers(n);
    vector <int> sum(n);
    vector <int> positive;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int temp; scanf_s("%d", &temp);
        if (temp > 0) {
            positive.push_back(i);
        }
        numbers[i] = temp;
        if (i == 0)
            sum[i] = numbers[i];
        else
            sum[i] = sum[i-1] + numbers[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << sum[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Ваш код совершенно не соответствует текстовому описанию того, что Вы делаете.

Comment: Вы знаете зачем слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы находится знак "галочка"?

Comment: Описываю алгоритм. Начало = 0, конец = 0, сумма = 0, макс.сумма = 0. Двигаем начало на 1, считаем новую сумму. Если она больше текущей, запоминаем её и индексы начала-конца. Если она стала меньше нуля - сбрасываем начало и конец на текущий элемент, а сумму на ноль... После завершения делаем корректировку - инкремент начала.

Comment: @Akina Что за специальное число "ноль"?

Comment: `натуральных цифр` -> `целых чисел` ?

Comment: @Igor не понял вопроса...

Comment: Судя по примеру вы ищите не сумму подпоследовательности, а сумму подмассива (непрерывного куска массива).

Answer (score 2):

Вроде так?

```
int main()
{
    size_t n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> a;
    copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin),n,back_inserter(a));
    partial_sum(a.begin(),a.end(),a.begin(),
                [](int a, int b){ return a + b >= 0 ? a + b : 0; });
    cout << *max_element(a.begin(),a.end());
}
```

Вот еще одна "[Кама Сутра](https://ideone.com/IYJnJh)" :)

```
struct Max
{
    int& operator*() { return cur; }
    void operator++(){ cur = mx = max(mx,mxe = max(0,mxe+cur)); }
private:
    int cur, mx = 0, mxe = 0;
};

int main()
{
    size_t n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << *copy_n(istream_iterator<int>(cin),n,Max{});

}
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А так? Жалко, что в С++ нет каких-то встроенных пайпов... чтоб из одного алгоритма в другой сразу передавать, без промежуточных контейнеров... Ну, или я чего-то не вижу. Конечно, можно итераторы хитрые написать, но это будет еще страшнее :)

Comment: Так всё работает. Да, без генераторов в стиле Питона неудобно. Может есть какие-нибудь итераторные библиотеки?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, вот такое вот извращение родилось... Не пайп, но... Одной `copy_n` обошлось :)

Comment: Пять минут читал пока понял что `cur` и вход и выход. Но вы не обязаны возращать максимум что `operator *`. Создайте итератор до `copy_n`, покормите его данными из `copy_n`, отдельным оператором выведите `mx`. Так код будет легче понять. Вообще, круто!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Нет, я пытался добиться именно минимальности кода в `main`, а не понятности кода... Я бы еще и `n` читал там же, но первая же идея потребовала несколько дополнительных строк итератора плюс некрасивое закрытие `cin` в итераторе... Вобщем, не стал извращаться.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a = [-1, 3, -2, 5, 3, -5, 2, 2];

let maxSum, i, j, sum;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  sum = a[i];
  maxSum = maxSum > sum? maxSum : sum;
  for (j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
    sum += a[j];
    maxSum = maxSum > sum? maxSum : sum;
  }
}

console.log('Max sum =', maxSum);
```

Comment: Ну перебор - это неспортивно!

Comment: Перебор это спортивно, пока не предложено лучшее решение.

Comment: В вашем решении есть одна тонкая ошибка. Если все числа отрицательные ответом должен быть ноль (сумма любого пустого подмассива). У вас не так.

Answer (score 0):

Я следовал классическому алгоритму, который описал [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) в [своём комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1363196/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8/1363256#comment2418900_1363196). Хранить числа не требуется. Хранятся два максимума: `max` - текущий максимум вообще и `max_ending_here` - максимальная сумма при условии что подмассив кончается на текущем элементе.

Когда приходит очередное значение `v`, оно добавляется к `max_ending_here`. Если сумма осталась положительной, то это новая максимальная сумма отрезка последовательности чисел (тут пауза чтобы подумать почему это правда). Если сумма стала отрицательной, её заменяют нулем - суммой пустой последовательности.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int max = 0;
    int max_ending_here = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int v;
        std::cin >> v;
        max_ending_here = std::max(0, max_ending_here + v);
        max = std::max(max, max_ending_here);
    }
    std::cout << max << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 max-subrange-sum.cpp
>
> $ echo 8 -1 3 -2 5 3 -5 2 2 | ./a.out 
> 9
> ```